# Can't delete the item I am clicking the delete button for - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple CRUD todo list and I previously had the delete functionality working properly. However, since adding a new piece of functionality, it no longer works and I cannot figure out why?

**[Here is a link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9nqnw0wx4)**

**Data**

```
const tasks = [
  { name: 'task1', isComplete: false },
  { name: 'task2', isComplete: true },
  { name: 'task3', isComplete: false },
]
```

**Delete function**

```
deleteTask(taskToDelete) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const tasks = prevState.tasks.filter(task => task.name !== taskToDelete);
      return { tasks };
    });
    console.log("Deleted task: "+taskToDelete)
  }
```

**How function is called:**

```
<button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>Delete</button>

handleDelete() {
    const taskToDelete = this.props.name;
    this.props.deleteTask(taskToDelete);
  }
```

Comment: in the onClick handler, how do you pass the task object to the event handler?

Comment: is this all on one component? if yes, in `handleDelete` is should be `this.deleteTask` not `this.props.deleteTask`.

Comment: The title of the dupe might not seem like a dupe, but you will find an answer there. Your state updates correctly, your issue is with the reconciliation for your `list-item`. You can fix this by adding a key to the parent div of that component. Take a look at the dupe post for more info.

Comment: @Chris - I have a key set for the list-item component: <ListItem key={index} {...task} {...props} />... Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Setting a key there doesn't help. React won't be able to figure out which `ListItem` corresponds to which `input`. If you read the dupe I'm sure you'll figure it out as it is emphasized where to put the key there. :)

Comment: Aha! Sorted it! I would have thought putting it in the list-item would have worked - Or at least it DID work until I implemented the boolean logic around which buttons are displayed. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @physicsboy glad you figured it out :)